# Dereference the name of a two dimension is same as the name. So what does dereference do?

Tags: c, pointers

What does dereference do?
Does it just return the value of the address in pointer.

WIKI says " It operates on a pointer variable, and returns an l-value equivalent to the value at the pointer address "

I got confused by the code below:

```
int p[2][2] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
printf("%p\t%p", p, *p);
```

I know that p is a pointer points to an array, like this

```
int (*p)[2];
```

Say p has the address of 0x003DEF4C. So *p doesn't should be the value in 0x003DEF4C ?
But it has the same value with p.

So it likes that dereference not just return the value of the address that the pointer points to.

Comment: The two-dimensional array decays to `int **` (just like a one-dimensional array decays to `int *`), so dereferencing it once using `*p` yields an `int *`.

Comment: Moreover, if the ints are allocated consecutively `p` will point to the same address as `*p` because both correspond to the address of `p[0][0]` (the address of the first element of the first array).

Comment: Note that when `*` operates on a multidimensional array, dereferencing once does **not** result in an lvalue. `p` is an array of arrays, even though it often behaves like/degenerates into a pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does dereference do? Does it just return the value of the address in pointer?

When you dereference a pointer, you get the value of what the pointer points to.

> Say p has the address of 0x003DEF4C. So *p doesn't should be the value in 0x003DEF4C ? But it has the same value with p.

This is true for the particular code you have. Take a look something a little different from yours.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int p1[2][2] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
   int* p2[2] = {NULL, NULL};
   int** p3 = NULL;
   int** p4 = NULL;

   p2[0] = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
   p2[1] = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
   p2[0][0] = 1;
   p2[0][1] = 2;
   p2[1][0] = 3;
   p2[1][1] = 4;

   p3 = (int**)malloc(2*sizeof(int*));

   p3[0] = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
   p3[1] = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
   p3[0][0] = 1;
   p3[0][1] = 2;
   p3[1][0] = 3;
   p3[1][1] = 4;

   p4 = (int**)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
   p4[0] = (int*)p4;
   p4[1] = p4[0]+2;
   p3[0][0] = 1;
   p3[0][1] = 2;
   p3[1][0] = 3;
   p3[1][1] = 4;

   printf("Address of p1:    %p\n", (void*)p1);
   printf("Address of p1[0]: %p\n", (void*)p1[0]);
   printf("Address of p1[1]: %p\n", (void*)p1[1]);
   printf("\n");

   printf("Address of p2:    %p\n", (void*)p2);
   printf("Address of p2[0]: %p\n", (void*)p2[0]);
   printf("Address of p2[1]: %p\n", (void*)p2[1]);
   printf("\n");

   printf("Address of p3:    %p\n", (void*)p3);
   printf("Address of p3[0]: %p\n", (void*)p3[0]);
   printf("Address of p3[1]: %p\n", (void*)p3[1]);
   printf("\n");

   printf("Address of p4:    %p\n", (void*)p4);
   printf("Address of p4[0]: %p\n", (void*)p4[0]);
   printf("Address of p4[1]: %p\n", (void*)p4[1]);
   printf("\n");

   /* Add code to free the allocated memory */
}
```

`p1` and everything it defines are created using memory on the stack. The address that `p1` points to is equal to address that `p1[0]` points to. They both point to an address in the stack.

`p2`, `p2[0]`, and `p2[1]` are created using memory on stack. `p2` points to an address in the stack memory. However memory allocated for `p2[0]` and `p2[1]` are from the heap. `p2` points to an address that is different from the address `p2[0]` points to.

`p3` is created on the stack but the address it points to are created from the heap. The address `p3[0]` points to is also created from the heap. Since they were created using separate calls to `malloc`, they point to different addresses.

`p4` is an example of how you can manipulate contiguous memory allocated from the heap to suit your own needs. Since we know we need to store 4 integers, we can allocate memory for them and make sure our pointers point to the right places. Manipulation of the heap memory for `p4` is analogous to what the compiler does when we create everything on the stack.

Here's a sample output when I run the program:

```
./test-22
Address of p1:    0x28ac18
Address of p1[0]: 0x28ac18
Address of p1[1]: 0x28ac20

Address of p2:    0x28ac10
Address of p2[0]: 0x80010458
Address of p2[1]: 0x80010468

Address of p3:    0x80010478
Address of p3[0]: 0x80010488
Address of p3[1]: 0x80010498

Address of p4:    0x800104a8
Address of p4[0]: 0x800104a8
Address of p4[1]: 0x800104b0
```

Comment: I think beacuse p is a pointer to an array, when dereference p, it returns the address of the array. In this particular code __int p[2][2]__, it just happens to be the same. So dereference not just return the value of address that the pointer points to. It depends the type of the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

What wiki says is true and very simple. Start with one dimension array

```
int p[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
printf("%p\t%d", (void *)p, *p);
```

`p` converts to the pointer to first element of array `p[]`. Dereferencing `p` will return the value stored at the address `p` points to. `*p` is an l-value which is equivalent to the variable `p[0]`.
Take example of simple assignments;

```
p[0] = 5;         // In this assignment p[0] is a l-value
*p   = p[0] + 1;  // p[0] is r-value and *p is l-value 
p[0] = *p - 5;    // p[0] is l-value and *p is r-value
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `printf` you are asking to:

- `p`: the address of your 2 dimensional array = address of the 1st element of the array
- `*p`: the address of the 1 dimensional sub-array = address of the 1st element of the array (which is the same address than above)

Note that if you look at the address of `(*p)[1]` for example (the 2nd sub-array) you should have something different.